# C++ std::vector::data Why do the returned pointer index and the vector index not match?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I found an example of std::vector in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/.

```
// vector::data
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector (5);

  int* p = myvector.data();

  *p = 10;
  ++p;
  *p = 20;
  p[2] = 100;

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (unsigned i=0; i<myvector.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << ' ' << myvector[i];
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

and the result is

```
myvector contains: 10 20 0 100 0
```

My question may be silly but I don't really understand what happened here. We got a direct pointer to the memory of the vector. Then we assign the value 10 for the first element (index 0), move to the second element and assign the value 20 to it (index 1). Finally, we assign the value 100 for the third element (index 2). Should the answer be as follow?

```
10 20 100 0 0
```

Comment: `p[2]` isn't accessing the third element (it's accessing the fourth, as your results show). Remember, you've already incremented `p`.

Comment: @Cornstalks - you should present you comment as an answer.

Comment: @max66: I consider this question to fall in the same realm as those caused by "a simple typographical error." As such, I personally prefer to add a very simple explanation in a comment (so the OP still gets help; I'm not totally heartless) while also voting to close.

Comment: Thinking of `p[2]` as `p + 2` may help you understand. This is probably just a good reason not to use cplusplus.com though, because the confusing part of their example has nothing to do with `data`

Comment: thank you all for clearing my thought. Just one more side question though: If Cpluplus is not a good reference source, then what site should I use for future references? I used learncpp.com for learning concept ( IMHO, it is a good source) but I have no other reference source though. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: The title is unlikely to help anyone find the question, even if they have the same issue. If you wish the question to remain open, I advise to make it easier to understand what the question is about: mentions of pointer, indexing, pointer arithmetic, ... may be more descriptive.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The title might not be particularly descriptive, but I don't think an improved title would help the question much, given that the question appears to come down to a general lack of understanding of pointer arithmetic, forgetting about `++p` or confusing `p[2]` with `myvector[2]`.

Comment: @Dukeling: I was on the fence between voting to close and attempting to save the question :) I am not sure indeed whether it can be saved.

Comment: Admittedly, I do lack knowledge about pointer as you all can see. I do want to make this question useful for others (beginners like myself). Does changing the title make things more specific? Or should I let the post be closed? Whichever way is better, I am glad to do it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This picture might help explain

```
int* p = myvector.data();
[   ] [   ] [   ] [   ] [   ]
  ^

*p = 10;
[10 ] [   ] [   ] [   ] [   ]
  ^

++p;
[10 ] [   ] [   ] [   ] [   ]
        ^

*p = 20;
[10 ] [20 ] [   ] [   ] [   ]
        ^

p[2] = 100; // [2] is relative to where p is
[10 ] [20 ] [   ] [100] [   ]
        ^
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of the example is right. Let me demonstrate it below -

```
std::vector<int> myvector (5); // creating vector with size 5, elements are 0,0,0,0,0

  int* p = myvector.data(); //taking reference of the vector, p now points the first element of vector

  *p = 10; // it means first element is now 10
  ++p; // p now points second element of the vector
  *p = 20; // 2nd element is now 20
  p[2] = 100; //p[2] is the 4th element now because of two position shifting and it is now 100
  // vectors elements are now 10, 20, 0, 100, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int> myvector (5); ==> [0,0,0,0,0]

int* p = myvector.data(); // p points to element 0

*p = 10;                  // element 0 is now 10
++p;                      // shift position of p to the next element
*p = 20;                  // element 1 is now 20
p[2] = 100;               // Using p as reference, go 2 positions to right and assign the value of 100 to the element found at that position.
```

The output is correctly `[10,20,0,100,0]`